# styles and scripts broken in jsp file

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsp

while working on a project, i got a problem with front end like the image below.

[image]

When the project is loaded, all styles and scripts are gone forever.
How can i fix this problem quickly. And also i tried to update the j query version by replacing old 'jquery.min.js' file with newer version.
any suggestions will be useful.

Comment: What do you mean gone forever? Does your project have a subfolder named `qubealliance/resources/assets/`? You should also add what you have tried to debug this, and maybe a screenshot / print out of the Firefox Console (F12).

Comment: thomas, its not like that.

Comment: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Learn More]
jquery.min.js:3 this is the error i got from console

Comment: Can you edit your question with the errors you get, and the steps you took to get them. I am guessing you have a network problem, or that the subfolders you are referencing are not really there. You might want to add a `./` before every import, so that the path is correct. Example: `href='./qubealliance/resources/bla/bla/bla'.`

Answer (score 0):

Since you pointed out that there is a syntax error on line 3 of your jquery file, you should check it.

Or just download the newer version of jquery, according to what the old version of the old jquery file you had.

2.x https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js

3.x https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js